# New build, weird scan lines or black screen. Need assistance

Tags: computer-building, build

Here is the build list:

- Motherboard: Asus ROG X570 VIII Hero
- CPU: AMD Ryzen 7 3800
- GPU: EVGA RTX 2080 Ti
- Secondary GPU: an older GTX 1080(from a prev build)
- Monitor: Acer Predator x34 and 2 1080p monitors(all 3 from prev build)
- Boot drive: Samsung 970 evo @ 1tb NVME
- Additional storage: Samsung 860 QVO SSD 2tb
- RAM: Corsair Vengeance rgb pro(4x16gb) ddr4 @ 3200
- PSU: Corsair RMX RM850w Gold

This is what I get:
[image]

Troubleshooting:

Please note: The only items I am using currently from my prev build is the display port cable, my Acer Predator x34 monitor, 2 1080p monitors and a GTX 1080 founders.

With this new build, I have a 3 monitor setup. The left and right monitors are 1080p screens, and in the center i have my Acer Predator that I've had for a few years. I am having an issue where at random times(about every 10-30 minutes while in use), the Predator monitor will either go black, or do this (see screenshot above). But it did not do this before. Considering that my old build was working as late as yesterday, and I was using the same monitor and Display Port cabling without any issues whatsoever, I figured the predator cant be the problem and instead probably a faulty GPU so I went and returned the RTX2080 to Amazon, and not wanting to wait, ran to Best Buy and got another RTX 2080. Put it back into the system, and the same issue. Almost immediately got the black screen.

Process of elimination, I figured i'd eliminate the RTX cards themselves being the issue since I've tried two new cards, and move onto the DisplayPort(DP) cable itself. Realizing i didn't have a spare, I ran back to BestBuy and got a new DP cable, installed it and nothing. The same issue, black screen or the image attached. I did notice though that whilst having the messup on the predator, that the two side monitors(HDMI) were ok and viewed perfectly fine. Still confused, i figured i have two things left to troubleshoot. The Predator itself, or the motherboard. With my luck, i figured it'd be the predator so further troubleshooting I kept everything the same and didn't remove anything. The only change being to take out the DP cable off of the RTX2080, and connect it to the GTX1080 and lo n behold. it works. Played a few games, and been on for a few hrs and no more issues. Its like nothing bad happened.

I'm confused because, since it works, it rules out the last two things which was the motherboard and the predator monitor. Been running the new build with the 1080 for a few hrs now and no issues. Last-minute I thought about the PSU, took it to pc part picker, and rounded everything up, for a total of around 550W. Also went online and used wattage calculators which both read around 729W. Both of  which my 850W covers. so yeah...not sure what the deal is. Im at my witts end and at this point, not sure what to do. I have effectively tested everything i could but to no avail. Any ideas? Anything im missing?Any assistance is greatly appreciated. Thank you kindly in advance.

Comment: Since you have very well covered hardware, see if you can get BIOS, Chipset, Video and Audio updated drivers for this computer. Sometimes Video and Audio have combined functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gonna place this response here so as to end it. Long story short, the solution was to remove the 1080. Once i did that for some reason it worked beautifuly. Guess **somwhow** the drivers were conflicting even though they are two cards from the same manufacturer and vendor.........who knew... anyways, problem solved.